# Why can't GCC assume that std::vector::size won't change in this loop?

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly

I claimed to a coworker that `if (i < input.size() - 1) print(0);` would get optimized in this loop so that `input.size()` is not read in every iteration, but it turns out that this is not the case!

```cpp
void print(int x) {
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

void print_list(const std::vector<int>& input) {
    int i = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
        print(input[i]);
        if (i < input.size() - 1) print(0);
    }
}
```

According to the [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/w2gfiJ) with gcc options `-O3 -fno-exceptions` we are actually reading `input.size()` each iteration and using `lea` to perform a subtraction!

```
        movq    0(%rbp), %rdx
        movq    8(%rbp), %rax
        subq    %rdx, %rax
        sarq    $2, %rax
        leaq    -1(%rax), %rcx
        cmpq    %rbx, %rcx
        ja      .L35
        addq    $1, %rbx
```

Interestingly, in Rust this optimization does occur. It looks like `i` gets replaced with a variable `j` that is decremented each iteration, and the test `i < input.size() - 1` is replaced with something like `j > 0`.

```rust
fn print(x: i32) {
    println!("{}", x);
}

pub fn print_list(xs: &Vec<i32>) {
    for (i, x) in xs.iter().enumerate() {
        print(*x);
        if i < xs.len() - 1 {
            print(0);
        }
    }
}
```

In the [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/J7hfW8) the relevant assembly looks like this:

```
        cmpq    %r12, %rbx
        jae     .LBB0_4
```

I checked and I am pretty sure `r12` is `xs.len() - 1` and `rbx` is the counter. Earlier there is an `add` for `rbx` and a `mov` outside of the loop into `r12`.

Why is this? It seems like if GCC is able to inline the `size()` and `operator[]` as it did, it should be able to know that `size()` does not change. But maybe GCC's optimizer judges that it is not worth pulling it out into a variable? Or maybe there is some other possible side effect that would make this unsafe--does anyone know?

Comment: Also `println` is probably a complex method, the compiler may have trouble proving that `println` doesn't mutate the vector.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Another thread would be data-race UB.  Compilers can and do assume *that* doesn't happen.  The problem here is the non-inline function call to `cout.operator<<()`.  The compiler doesn't know that this black-box function doesn't get a reference to the `std::vector` from a global.

Comment: @PeterCordes: you're right that other threads aren't a standalone explanation, and the complexity of `println` or `operator<<` is key.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know the semantics of these external methods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The non-inline function call to `cout.operator<<(int)` is a black box for the optimizer (because the library is just written in C++ and all the optimizer sees is a prototype; see discussion in comments).  It has to assume any memory that could possibly be pointed to by a global var has been modified.

(Or the `std::endl` call.  BTW, why force a flush of cout at that point instead of just printing a `'\n'`?)

e.g. **for all it knows, `std::vector<int> &input` is a reference to a global variable, and one of those function calls modifies that global var**.  (Or there's a global `vector<int> *ptr` somewhere, or there's a function that returns a pointer to a `static vector<int>` in some other compilation unit, or some other way that a function could get a reference to this vector without being passed a reference to it by us.

If you had a local variable whose address had never been taken, the compiler *could* assume that non-inline function calls couldn't mutate it.  Because there'd be no way for any global variable to hold a pointer to this object.  (**This is called [Escape Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis)**).  That's why the compiler can keep `size_t i` in a register across function calls.  (`int i` can just get optimized away because it's shadowed by `size_t i` and not used otherwise).

It could do the same with a local `vector` (i.e. for the base, end_size and end_capacity pointers.)

ISO C99 has a solution for this problem: `int *restrict foo`.  Many C++ compiles support `int *__restrict foo` to promise that memory pointed to by `foo` is *only* accessed via that pointer.  Most commonly useful in functions that take 2 arrays, and you want to promise the compiler they don't overlap.  So it can auto-vectorize without generating code to check for that and run a fallback loop.

The OP comments:

> In Rust a non-mutable reference is a global guarantee that no one else is mutating the value you have a reference to (equivalent to C++ `restrict`)

That explains why Rust can make this optimization but C++ can't.

---

#### Optimizing your C++

Obviously you should use `auto size = input.size();` once at the top of your function so the compiler knows it's a loop invariant.  C++ implementations don't solve this problem for you, so you have to do it yourself.

You might also need `const int *data = input.data();` to hoist loads of the data pointer from the `std::vector<int>` "control block" as well.  **It's unfortunate that optimizing can require very non-idiomatic source changes.**

Rust is a much more modern language, designed after compiler developers learned what was possible in practice for compilers.  It really shows in other ways, too, including portably exposing some of the cool stuff CPUs can do via `i32.count_ones`, rotate, bit-scan, etc.  It's really dumb that ISO C++ still doesn't expose any of these portably, except `std::bitset::count()`.

Comment: OP's code still has the test if the vector is taken by-value. So even though GCC could optimize in that case, it doesn't do so.

Comment: The standard defines the behaviour of `operator<<` for those operand types; so in Standard C++ it's not a black box and the compiler can assume it does what the documentation says.  Maybe they want to support library developers adding nonstandard behaviour ...

Comment: @walnut: hmm, interesting.  And it doesn't even hoist either load.  I'm not shocked it doesn't restructure the loop to peel the last iteration or something, but it could have loaded the pointer members into registers.

Comment: @M.M: Sure, but it's only implemented by writing `operator<<`  in C++, not making it a compiler builtin that the compiler "knows about".  That only happens for a few very important functions like memcpy and strlen, or that constant-propagation can happen through like sqrt and many other math functions.  (`printf` is also a built-in function so the compiler can transform it into `puts` for some simple formats.)  **TL:DR: most of the non-template standard library functions are just written in C++ and the optimizer only sees a prototype, so for its POV it is a black box.**

Comment: The optimizer could be fed the behaviour that the standard mandates  , my point is that this optimization is permitted by the standard but the compiler vendor chooses to implement in the way you describe and forego this optimization

Comment: @M.M: yes, agreed.

Comment: @M.M  The standard doesn't require that operator << not modify any   std::vector<int> that `input` could possibly point to. Aside from the fact that there could be in implementation defined vector that operator << uses, it's possible for a user defined class that's been associated with `cout` to change the vector.

Comment: @RossRidge can you clarify what you mean by "a user defined class that's been associated with cout"  .  Re your first point, the library functions can be assumed to not modify other random objects unless specified (there's some text in the standard to that effect)

Comment: @M.M It didn't say random object, I said an implementation defined vector. There's nothing in the standard that prohibits an implementation from having an implementation defined vector that operator << modifies and allowing access this vector in an implementation defined manner.  `cout` allows an object of a user defined class derived from `streambuf` to be associated with the stream using `cout.rdbuf`.  Similarly an object derived from `ostream` can be associated with `cout.tie`.

Comment: @RossRidge The implementation can control whether or not such a vector exists

Comment: @M.M GCC doesn't however. It's not a complete implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! The two main takeaways from me are: (1) operator<< doesn't get inlined and is a black box (makes sense that it would be in a different compilation unit, now that I think about it), and (2) even though Rust and C++ both use `&` for references, they are very different: in Rust a non-mutable reference is a global guarantee that no one else is mutating the value you have a reference to (equivalent to `restrict`), while in C++ a const reference is a local restriction against you mutating the value you have a reference to, which is why rustc can make this optimization.

Comment: Also @M.M's comments describe what I would have expected too. I am kind of surprised that the C++ library implementation and compiler don't coordinate in this way. It seems like a micro-optimization here but there must be other cases where the impact would be large...

Comment: @PeterCordes - I wouldn't be so confident about local vectors: as soon as any member function gets out-of-lined, the locals have effectively escaped because the `this` pointer is implicitly passed. This could happen in practice as early as the constructor. Consider [this simple loop](https://godbolt.org/z/fv3Sba) - I only checked the gcc main loop (from `L34:` to `jne L34`), but it is definitely behaving as if the vector members have escaped (loading them from memory each iteration).